# Filter list of points by distance and score

Tags: python, list, filtering

I'm faced with a problem I'm trying to find an elegant solution to, but I don't have the in-depth knowledge of various libraries to achieve this yet.

I have a list of an object of the class 'Point' that contains an x and y coordinate and a score.
`pts = [pt_1, pt_2, pt_3 ... pt_n]`

Now, I need to find a way to filter this list, so from two points in the list that are too close to each other, we remove one with a lower score.

So, given two points in list pts, `pt_x` and `pt_y`, if their Euclidean distance is smaller than threshold T, compare their score, and remove the point from the list with a smaller score. I have all the necessary classes and comparison function implemented, I'm just not sure how to efficiently achieve the filtering of the list and wasn't able to successfuly do so.

```py
for idx, ptp in enumerate(pts[:]):
        for pto in pts[idx+1:]:
            if ptp.is_match(pto, 60):
                if ptp.score < pto.score:
                    pts.remove(ptp)
                    break
                else:
                    pts.remove(pto)
    return pts
```

The above was my attempt but didn't work.

To give a better idea, here's an input and expected output given `Point(x, y, score)` and distance threshold of 3 units:

Input:

```py
pts = [
    Point(11, 10, 0.97),
    Point(10, 11, 0.96),
    Point(50, 47, 0.87),
    Point(10, 10, 0.98),
    Point(78, 56, 0.99)
]
```

Output:

```
pts = [
    Point(50, 47, 0.87),
    Point(10, 10, 0.98),
    Point(78, 56, 0.99)
]
```

Point class:

```py
class Point:

    def __init__(self, x, y, score):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.score = score

    def is_match(self, point, thresh=50):
        return ((self.x - point.x) ** 2 + (self.y - point.y) ** 2) ** 0.5 <= thresh
```

EDIT:

Found a better solution that works for arbitrarily large samples, but is far from fast and elegant:

```py
idx = 0
while idx < len(pts):
    pt = pts[idx]
    pt_s = list(filter(lambda ptt: ptt.is_match(pt, distance), pts[idx:]))
    if len(pt_s) > 1:
        max_pt = max(pt_s, key=operator.attrgetter('score'))
        pt_s.remove(max_pt)
        for pt in pt_s:
            pts.remove(pt)
    else:
        idx += 1

return pts
```

Comment: What do you mean by it didn't work? It looks ok to me. Did you get an error? You didn't give a reproducible example so can't debug.

Comment: As I don't have the class you are using i cannot make a working example, but I think the most efficient way would be to use a [KDTree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html) object from scipy and it `query_ball_tree` or `query_pairs` methods

Comment: You would also need to give us the definition of your "Points" class in order for us to reproduce this...

Comment: Or at the very least, we need to see the definition of the "is_match" method in that class

Comment: Added. Curiously enough, it works well on the small example I provided below, but doesn't work on large samples. From debugging, it seems to me the `idx` variable seems to grow way beyond the size of `pts` after a certain point when several points have been removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you're removing elements from a list while iterating over it. This is generally a bad idea. You can  modify it slightly to store a set of elements scheduled for removal like so

```
newps = []
ignore = set()
while ps:
    p = ps.pop()
    if p not in ignore:
        for i,o in enumerate(ps):
            if o not in ignore and p.is_match(o,3):
                if p.score < o.score:
                    break
                else:
                    ignore.add(o)
        else:
            newps.append(p)

print(newps)
```

Note: the else clause of a for loop executes when the loop completed, which is to say there was no `break`

While we're at it, why not go further and do away with lists all-together to make things cleaner.

```
ps = {
    Point(11, 10, 0.97),
    Point(10, 11, 0.96),
    Point(50, 47, 0.87),
    Point(10, 10, 0.98),
    Point(78, 56, 0.99)
}

newps = set()
while ps:
    p = ps.pop()
    remove = set()
    for o in ps:
        if p.is_match(o,3):
            if p.score < o.score:
                break
            else:
                remove.add(o)
    else:
        newps.add(p)
    ps.difference_update(remove)
print(newps)
```